# Is Smart Table compatible with Angular 2.0?

Tags: angularjs, angular, smart-table

I was looking at the documentation for Smart Table (https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) and all the examples seem to use Angular 1.0.  I was wondering if Smart Table can be used with Angular 2.0?

(Note that I found another product that supports tables in Angular 2 called ng2-smart-table [https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table], but it appears to have no relation to the original Smart Table, which I'd like to still be able to use when I migrate to Angular 2.0)

Comment: your link to smarttable throws 404. What is that you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I am migrating the existing web application from angularJS to angular V4.03 and would like to help you understand that there is really a large structural difference between v2 and v4 but functionality remains the same. ng2-smart-table/akveo is perfectly stable with both the version.

You might find it difficult to customize the style at first but a little practice with ::ng-deep will overcome your troubles. Also, you will find an active team support with the product.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was also hunting for smart tables and found both the tables you have mentioned. I believe angular-smart-table is for AngularJS. I check their repo carefully. The last commit is shown on 5th September 2016. And author is promoting new ambitious project. I concluded that he doesnt want to upgrade current project for sure.

Now for the ng2-smart-table, the name is bit deceiving. Their current versions expect you to be using Angular 4. You have to use their 0.6.x version with Angular 2. The biggest drawback is, these tables doesnt support datasource from server side. Data has to be statically defined. They are working on API/Server datasource. I am watching the repo!!!